# Why using asyncronus function if then you await their response?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization, async.js

Why we using async function if then we use await for waiting their response, in this case what's the difference between a syncronus function?

Comment: When `await` is hit within the function, the function returns and the code after the function call can run (your code is still asynchronous). With synchronous code, the function would block the code after the function call from running until the entire function call is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comparison between using async / await and then :

```
function fetchData() {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json());
}

async function asyncMain() {
    console.log('Start');

    console.log(await fetchData());

    console.log('End');
}

function main() {
    console.log('Start');

    fetchData().then(data => { console.log(data) });

    console.log('End');
}

main();
// Output
// Start
// End
// { "userId": 1, id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem", "completed": false}

asyncMain();
// Output
// Start
// { "userId": 1, id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem", "completed": false}
// End
```

async function allow you to use await + make the function return a promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

As you can see, await block the function execution and wait for the result before printing 'End'. While syncronious function print 'End' then print the result once the request to the api is resolved.

To simplify, await means "wait for the answer then execute the rest of the code" while then means "when you receive the response do ..." then it execute then end of the code